# Get name of current nox session

Tags: python, nox

How do I get the name of the currently running nox session? For example, to use the name to customize a coverage file:

```
import nox


@nox.session(python=['3.6', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9'])
def test(session):
    session.install('.')
    session.install('pytest', 'pytest-cov')
    session.env['COVERAGE_FILE'] = f'.coverage.{session.name}'  # <-- what do I put here?
    session.run('python', '-m', 'pytest', '--cov', 'tests/')
```

Answer (score 1):

This information is available at `Session._runner.friendly_name`:

```
import nox


@nox.session(python=['3.6', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9'])
def test(session):
    session.install('.')
    session.install('pytest', 'pytest-cov')
    session.env['COVERAGE_FILE'] = f'.coverage.{session._runner.friendly_name}'
    session.run('python', '-m', 'pytest', '--cov', 'tests/')
```

Because this requires accessing a private attribute, it should be considered unstable in addition to being undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

This was [recently implemented](https://github.com/theacodes/nox/pull/386) as `Session.name` and will be included in the next release.

```py
import nox


@nox.session(python=['3.6', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9'])
def test(session):
    session.install('.')
    session.install('pytest', 'pytest-cov')
    session.env['COVERAGE_FILE'] = f'.coverage.{session.name}'
    session.run('python', '-m', 'pytest', '--cov', 'tests/')
```

Full disclosure: I wrote the PR that added this.